# Difference between behaviour in live code and local code

Tags: angularjs

I have a user controller with this content,

```
$scope.followUnfollowUser = function(user) {
    //If followed - unfollow
    if (user.isFollowed) {

        unfollowUser.unfollowUser(user).then(function() {
            user.isFollowed=!user.isFollowed
        }, function() {
        })

        Notification.success(user.name + ' wordt niet meer gevolgd.');

    } else {

        followUser.create({
            followed_id: user.id
        }).then(function() {
            user.isFollowed=!user.isFollowed
        }, function() {
        })

        Notification.success(user.name + ' wordt nu gevolgd.');
    }
  init();
}

var init = function () {

  loadCurrent_user.loadCurrent_user().then(function(response) {
    $scope.current_user = response.data;

    usersService.loadUsers().then(function(response) {
      $scope.users = response.data;
      //Iterate and create isFollowed property
      angular.forEach($scope.users, function(user) {
        user.isFollowed = isFollowed(user.id);
      })
      console.log ($scope.current_user.following)
    })

    var isFollowed = function(userId) {

      var following = $scope.current_user.following;
      for (var i = 0; i < following.length; i++) {
        if (following[i].id == userId) {
            return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }

  });

}
```

And this template,

```
%ul{"ng-repeat" => "user in users"}
  %li
    name: {{ user.name }}
    %br

    %a{"ng-click" => "followUnfollowUser(user)"}
      -# {{ user.isFollowed }}
      {{ user.isFollowed ? "Unfollow user" : "Follow user"}}
```

When I use my app locally to follow or unfollow a user my `console.log ($scope.current_user.following)` gets updated with the correct amount of objects.

For example locally I'm following 3 users. The console.log returns 3 objects. If I unfollow a user the console.log returns 2 objects.

But on my live server the `console.log ($scope.current_user.following)` doesn't get updated with the object. For example, when I follow 0 users on my live server and visit the user page. The `console.log ($scope.current_user.following)` returns 0 objects (since I'm not following a user). When I click on the follow link for a user I get the notification that I'm following a user, if I check my `current_user.json` it shows that I'm following a user, and when I check `relationships.json` it also shows that I'm following a user. But my `console.log ($scope.current_user.following)` returns 0 objects.

When I click the link to follow another user, then the `console.log ($scope.current_user.following)` returns 1 object (the user is previously followed, while it should show 2 objects. The previous and current followed user object).

So on the live server the `console.log ($scope.current_user.following)` is always one behind.

Comment: try to use {{ current_user }} on html to view the real content. But, anyway, do you have any problem with the data viewed on browser?

Comment: The `{{ user.isFollowed ? "Unfollow user" : "Follow user"}}` doesn't update propperly.

Comment: Doesn't seem very efficient to reload all users every time you make a small change to one of them

Comment: Apparently, there are a gap because the live status and status after $promise success. You can try to set a transitory status on screen (something like user.waiting = true) and use this status to apply some css

Comment: I've tracked the response from `loadCurrent_user.loadCurrent_user().then(function(response)` with console.log and the response doesn't equal the actual current_user data.

Comment: I've found the problem, and the answer (posted below). Maybe someone can shine some light on to why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tracking the flow of my data I found out that my `loadCurrent_user.loadCurrent_user().then(function(response)` function in the `init` was not synchronized with the actual data. I don't know why though. But moving the `loadCurrent_user.loadCurrent_user` and the `usersService.loadUsers` function outside the init, and into the actual `followUnfollowUser` if/else statement worked. Now the data is correctly retrieved and the view updated.